# Active participation during election

Tags: discussion, election

So, I've done it; I've [nominated myself for dba.SE moderator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election).

Unfortunately, I am shipping off to Alaska for SQL Cruise starting May 24th, and from what I understand the election runs through May 28th. My question is: is there anything in that final few days that requires me to be online and actively participating in the election? If so, I may have to withdraw, because even when I do have connectivity during the trip, it won't be good and it won't be for long.

Comment: [nooooooooooooooo](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: I think withdrawing would be the fair thing to do...... :)

Comment: The only thing would be the town hall chats, but I expect that might could be arranged before you leave. We will have to ask the Community mods.

Answer (score 6):

Mechanically speaking, a candidate can technically just leave the site right after posting their nomination for the duration of the election, to address what kind of *required* things are needed of them. Which is none.

The times that it would be handy to be around, however, are:

- [There's a chatroom for the election](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8762/database-administrators-2013-moderator-election). While there are no official events there, it's a good place for people to ask passerby questions or hash out things or otherwise discuss the events of the election, so being around helps. Since no events, there's no schedule around it (unless the community itself organizes something, which is encouraged).
- [There's a Q&A that will be hosted](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/2013-moderator-election-qa-question-collection). During this nomination phase (until the 20th), we will be collecting questions. The actual questionnaire will open up after that, so since that's before your departure, it would be good to try and submit your answers before then. This is purely optional, though.
- After the election, if you win, there's a moderator agreement you'll have to agree to. You don't have to do it immediately when you get your diamond, but as soon as you get back then it would be handy for you to do that. This could theoretically be done on a limited connection if you're at least able to access the site.